# Notation for the area outside of an area?

Tags: geometry, notation, terminology

Given how one can denote the intersection of areas as $A_1 \cap A_2$, it would make sense if one could use other set-theoretic notation in regards to geometric objects.

So I wonder, is the area outside of an area $A_1$ denotable as $A_1^C$? And if so, I assume one could call it "the complement of $A_1$?" If this notation/terminology is not conventionally used, then what is?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference#Properties

Comment: Yes, the notation you use is standard and would be understood. (I don't see how the symmetric difference of two sets is relevant here.)

Comment: @Joe Thank and that goes for referring to $A_1^C$ as "the complement of $A_1$" too?

Comment: @user110391: Yep, that is how it is usually read. The only catch is that the notation only makes sense when you have a "universal" set $\Omega$ that the complements are taken relative to. For instance, if you were talking about a subset of the plane, then it would make sense to set $\Omega = \mathbb R^2$. Then, $A^c=\Omega\setminus A=\mathbb R^2\setminus\Omega$.

Comment: Sorry, I should have written $A^c=\Omega\setminus A=\mathbb R^2\setminus A$.

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of *why* one denotes the intersection of areas as $A_1\cap A_2$. It's not because it "reminds us of sets" or anything like that, but because $A_1$ and $A_2$ *are* sets. Geometric objects are not separate from sets, they *are* sets

Answer (score 0):

The complement of any set A contained in $\Omega$ would be $A^c$ or $A'$ where $A'=\left\{x \in \Omega \mid x \notin A\right\}$.

[image: Complement of a set]

Comment: This is not answering the question and is instead stating something already heavily implied in the question. Your answer thus provides neither the requested info, nor new info at all. Do not think Venn diagrams represent geometric shapes, they represent sets/propositions.

Comment: @user110391 I tried to use the Venn diagram to illustrate an example, they simply represent sets.